# Set selected row for a given value in UIPickerView iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

In my app, I ask a worker to choose a letter from the alphabet (for example A) and the alphabet will have some explications that will appear in a `UIPickerView` with 3 # rows.

I want my `UIPickerView` to be display contents based on the indicator that has been chosen by a worker.

How do I do this?

Comment: How do you store the data to be displayed on selection ? plz post some code

Comment: // selection. in this case, it means showing the appropriate row in the middle
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated;  // scrolls the specified row to center. please provide some code so That I can Get What exact issue is

Answer (score 1):

selection. in this case, it means showing the appropriate row in the middle

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

scrolls the specified row to center.

please provide some code so That I can Get What exact issue is